# Force function in separate thread on Corona SDK, similar to "dispatch_async block" in iOS

Tags: multithreading, lua, coronasdk

Can a **function** be forced to be called in a separate **thread** using Corona SDK?

How?

edit:
So what I felt was slacking down my system was not depending on asynchronous calls. It was a table view that had to be filled with 1000+ elements. Turns out, it was a bug in an earlier version of corona SDK. Updating to the latest build made the table-view row insertion much more rapid.

Comment: What are you trying to do in a separate thread?  Many things like network calls, transitions, timers, etc are effectively asynchronous in Corona SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get in Lua (and Corona SDK) is coroutines but these are not really threads but rather (to quote Programming in Lua):

> A coroutine is similar to a thread (in the sense of multithreading): a
>   line of execution, with its own stack, its own local variables, and
>   its own instruction pointer; but sharing global variables and mostly
>   anything else with other coroutines. The main difference between
>   threads and coroutines is that, conceptually (or literally, in a
>   multiprocessor machine), a program with threads runs several threads
>   concurrently. Coroutines, on the other hand, are collaborative: A
>   program with coroutines is, at any given time, running only one of its
>   coroutines and this running coroutine only suspends its execution when
>   it explicitly requests to be suspended.

http://www.lua.org/pil/9.html

Unfortunately, if you approach coroutines hoping that they will be like threads you'll be disappointed.

Comment: Turns out . It was not asynchronousity that was my problem. I'm gonna accept this answer anyway because you are indeed correct.